# Append jquery tabla

Tags: jquery

Actualmente inserto datos en los td del body de mi tabla de esta forma:

```
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr><!--aca necesito insertar otro th-->
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



$('#table1').append('<tr id='+token+'><td>'+variable1+'</td><td >'+variable2+'</td><td>'+variable4+'</td><td><button  type="button" onclick="Eliminar()" class="btn btn-warning"> Eliminar </button></td></tr>')
```

De que forma podría insertar en el th en el thead de mi tabla ?

```
$('#table1 thead').append('<tr><th>Prueba</th></tr>');//estaba probando con esto pero no lo inserta de forma correcta
```

Comment: Ya he entendido el problema con el comentario `//aca necesito insertar otro th` recuerda que en html es: `<!-- aca necesito insertar otro th -->`

Comment: Ya que he visto que se me han adelantado varias respuestas, yo te sugeriría hacer la búsqueda del elemento usando `#table1 > thead > tr` usando el [selector de hijos](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) de la manera que te sugiero en mi respuesta. Así evitas tener que encadenar múltiples llamadas `.find()`. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo te sugeriría hacer la búsqueda del elemento usando `#table1 > thead > tr` usando el [selector de hijos](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('#table1 > thead > tr').append('<th>Prueba</th>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr> <!-- aca necesito insertar otro th -->
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de esta forma, primero tu tabla `$('#table1')` después de eso encuentra el tag `<thead>` nuevamente busca tu tag `<tr>` y ahora si le das `append()`

```js
$('#table1').find('thead').find('tr').append('<th>Direccion</th>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>//aca necesito insertar otro th
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso, lo que yo haría sería coger la tabla por su id, coges el último`th` de la tabla y después insertas otro, así:

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
</head>
<body>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>

    </tr>//aca necesito insertar otro th
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
<script> $("#table1 th:last").after("<th>Prueba</th>"); </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Debes intentar con lo siguiente:

```
$('#table1 thead').find('tr').append( /*lo que necesites agregar*/ )
```

Comment: -2? no es tan mala la rta como para freirlo a negativos.